# get SHA256 has of certificate chain of my certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority, hash

I got my server certificate `mycert.pem` by command:

`cho -n | openssl s_client -connect <my.server.hostname> | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > mycert.pem`.

I would like to see the certificate chain hash value.

My question is:

How can I use command line to get the **SHA256 has**h of **certificate chain** of `mycert.pem`?

I mean something like this as output:

```
Peer certificate chain:
     sha256/afwiKY3SxoMmLkuRW1l7QsPZTJPwDS2pdDROQjXw8ig=: CN=publicobject.com, OU=PositiveSSL
     sha256/klO23nT8ehFDXCfx3eHTDRESMz3asj1muO+4aIdjiuY=: CN=COMODO RSA Secure Server CA
     sha256/grX4Ta9OpZx6tSHkmCrvpApTQGo67CYDnvprLg5yRME=: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
     sha256/lCppFqbprlJ3EcVFAkeip0+44VaoJUymbnOaEUk7tEU=: CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Comment: What's in `mycert.pem`? Is it the fullchain? Or is it just the leaf certificate? Where did you get the output you posted here in the question? Was this manually constructed?

Comment: @Andrew, I updated my post.

Comment: Where does your sample output come from? What are you trying to do -- looks like pinning? (If pinning, you could use Scott Helme's generator: https://report-uri.com/home/pkp_hash ) Can you share the input for your sample output?